# What is the difference between vegetarian and vegan?

Tags: veganism, terminology

I read the [following questions](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/276/is-there-a-difference-between-vegan-and-plant-based) which I found pretty impressive, but it left me with this question about the difference between the 2 "categories" - vegetarian and vegan. In easy terms, what would be the big differences between both in regards to eating, supporting the world in regard to animal and any other case that has an impact.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Typically* (at least in Europe and the Americas), although the definition varies, vegetarians are those who at least do not **consume** products made from the body of an animal that has been killed. This means avoiding:

- meat including poultry
- fish including shellfish
- gelatin
- cheese made with animal rennet
- alcoholic drinks made using products from dead animals

Vegans attempt to avoid **all** products derived from animals or which exploit or harm animals in their production process*, whether the products are consumed or otherwise, and regardless of whether the animal is killed. This means, in addition to the above, vegans also avoid consuming or otherwise using:

- dairy products
- eggs
- honey, pollen and beeswax
- shellac
- leather and fur
- silk and wool
- products tested on animals

*this may be aspirational. It is almost impossible to avoid some complicity in harm caused to non-human animals, for example, in producing some crops, measures must be taken to deter "pests", which harm them.